# Quadtree for collisions with latitude/longitude (earth size)

Tags: google-maps, data-structures, 2d, collision, quadtree

I have a Google Map and a server sends a list of objects that have a position with a small radius (100m max). I need to quickly be able to know if a position is colliding with something in the list and draw on the map everything.

I'm thinking I should use a Quadtree (very useful in 2D collisions for games) but my issue is I'm not limited to a screen but to the earth !
Sure, if I have 100 objects it's not a problem but at any time the server can send me new objects that I need to add to the list and so my Quadtree could drastically change or become unbalanced.
What should I do ? Should I still use a Quadtree and modify the entire tree if a new element is added outside of the current boundaries ? Should I set the boundaries to the max latitude longitude (but could have issue with double precision) ? Or does someone knows a better data structure for that type of problem ?

rXp

Comment: Just set the boundaries to min/max longitude and latitude (-90.0 to 90.0, -180.0 to 180.0); QuadTrees work well in this situation but maybe a KD-Tree or Axis Aligned Bounding Box Tree would be worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid issues with double precision, especially at the splitting border of a quad cell, it is advisable to use integer coordinates in the quad tree.

convert double lat/lon to int by multiplying with 1E6, this results in a precision of about 10cm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a space-filling-curve, for example a z curve.